# View phone from PC

Tags: android, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 laptop and an android phone. I need a service that lets me view and interact with my phone through my computer. They both have WiFi and Bluetooth, and I can connect it to my PC via USB.

Comment: You can make your pick from my app listing: [Manage your Android Device from your Computer](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_remotemanagement). You can expect best recommendations if you [edit] your question and elaborate a little on what interactions you want to process ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full remote access to Android device](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17296/full-remote-access-to-android-device)

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the good and old Teamviewer, it will fit all your needs I think.

Answer (score 0):

Being searching solutions for [another question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/49978/29879), I have seen a few alternatives. Among them, I want to recommend [AirDroid](https://www.airdroid.com/es-es/), which will probably do everything you need.